# Doctrine DQL count with condition on joined table

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the following entities:

```php
class Restaurant
{
    // ...
}

class Order
{
    /**
     * The Restaurant this order belongs to.
     *
     * @var Restaurant
     */
    protected $restaurant;

    /**
     * The status of this order: 'pending', 'accepted' or 'rejected'.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $status;

    // ...
}
```

A Restaurant can have zero or more Orders.

I'd like to query all the Restaurants along with the total count of Orders, as well as the count of Orders in each status.

I came up with the following query:

```sql
SELECT r, COUNT(o.id) AS totalOrders
FROM Restaurant r
LEFT JOIN Order o WITH o.restaurant = r
GROUP BY r.id
```

How can I get the count of `pendingOrders`, `acceptedOrders` and `rejectedOrders` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

```sql
SELECT r, COUNT(o.id) AS totalOrders,
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pendingOrders,
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 'accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS acceptedOrders,
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 'rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rejectedOrders
FROM Restaurant r
LEFT JOIN Order o WITH o.restaurant = r
GROUP BY r.id
```